# Can we force the initial state of a neural network to produce an "unknown" class?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

Has anyone investigated ways to initialize a network so that everything is considered "unknown" at the start?

When you consider the ways humans learn, if something doesn't fit a class well enough, it falls into an "unknown category".

I would argue we all ultimately do some type of correlation matching internally with a certain threshold existing for recognition.

Deep networks don't currently have this ability, everything falls into a class. What I'm curious about is how might we force a network to initially classify things as "unknown" as the default state.